# php oo reference class member

Tags: php, oop, reference

```
class Foo{
   private &$member;
   function __construct(&$member){ $this->member = &$member; }
   function doSmtg(){//changes member }
   function doSmtgElse(){//changes member }
}
$myMember = "";
foo = new Foo($myMember);
foo->doSmtg();
echo $myMember;
```

I would like to pass $mymember to the constructor of Foo as a ref, so that the changes to it will directly be changed on the $myMember variable aswell.

My code is currently wrong, I get error about unexpected '&' at `private &$member;`
So I guess something is wrong with my syntax on refrence usage?

I tried to follow: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Don't do that. That leads to hard to diagnose bugs and unexpected behavior.

Comment: @JohnConde is right, you should make "doSmtg" take your value as parameter, and then return the modified value, so the main is aware of the changes, and the main become maintainable

Comment: but by doing this i can modify `$myMember`and still be able to return someing within the function, also isn't this better in performance ?

Comment: If you want to return multiple values, you should modify the class attribute, `private $member` and then, the main calls `getMember()`

Comment: yes, but isn't using ref. to do this better performance-wise ? isn't that why the sort methoed uses a refrence to the given array ? idk...

Comment: It depends what you do indeed, if you are in an loop, you may gain 0.1% performances using references...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot define a variable reference. You can only have a variable holding a reference to another variable.

Other that that, you don't have to tell PHP what kind of stuff you want to put in your variable when defining.

Therefore: 
`private &$member;` can just be 
`private $member;`

Comment: accepted since it gave me the correct solution on the usage of reference variable in php.

Answer (score 1):

Please do it that way :

```
class Foo{
   private $member1;
   private $member2;
   function __construct(){}
   function doSmtg($member1, $member2){
      $this->member1 = $member1;
      $this->member2 = $member2;
      //changes member1 and 2 
   }
   function doSmtgElse(){
      $this->member1 = $member1;
      $this->member2 = $member2;
      //changes member1 and 2 
   }
   function getMember1(){
      return $this->member1;
   }
   function getMember2(){
      return $this->member2;
   }
}
$myMember1 = "";
$myMember2 = "";
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->doSmtg($myMember1, $myMember2);
echo $foo->getMember1.", ".$foo->getMember2;
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you're doing wrong:

```
private &$member;
```

That is not allowed in PHP.
Why are you using references at all? References work differently in PHP. PHP references are not the same as other languages like C or C++.